# how to use "$in" to find all with mongodb or mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

like this:
I want use `$in` to find all
let `db.task.find()` === `db.task.find('status': {'$in': [???]})`
how can I code it?

Comment: Why not use db.task.find('status': {'$nin': []}) ?

Comment: @ Sarath Nair use this can not find anything

Comment: You are you trying to do? It is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

**$in :** The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array.

Example : db.inventory.find( { qty: { $in: [ 5, 15 ] } } )

So I dont think you will get all using this.

You can check : https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how such a use case came. If you really want to use `$in` for finding all documents, you must execute a `distinct` query before find like shown below:

```
var allStatus = db.task.distinct('status')
db.task.find('status': {'$in': allStatus})
```

I think this will get you what you need.